# Gitlab external_url unreachable

Tags: gitlab

I just installed Gitlab 7.0 using the Debian Omnibus installer onto an Oracle Linux Server release 6.4 server. Everything appears to have run fine and the Gitlab server has started correctly but for some reason navigating to the login page does not work.

I've changed all the ports via gitlab.rb to be the following as on the same server I have httpd and tomcat running:

```
 Change the external_url to the address your users will type in their browser
 external_url 'http://255.255.255.255:6000'

 unicorn['port'] = 6001
 redis['port'] = 6002
 postgresql['port'] = 6003
```

Attempts to telnet into the server via the ip address or localhost result in the following message being returned:

```
telnet localhost 6000
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I'm pretty much at a loss as to what to do. I would like to point out that not changing the ports and shutting down httpd and tomcat brings up gitlab just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't a Gitlab issue but an issue with Chrome blocking percieved dangerous ports. Navigating to the same url using IE opened gitlab just fine.